# Galaxy S9 not using proper drawable resources

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

I am working on development of a dark mode for an application in android studio. This application uses a custom background element for the EditText which I have called custom_edit_text. To be assured of backwards compatibility I have created a "layout" and a "layout-v29" folder for the dark mode changes, and similarly I have created a "drawable" and "drawable-v29" for the custom_edit_text.

This has worked for devices around the office and on the emulator, however a fellow employees galaxy s9 will not display the new drawable and instead defaults to using the "drawable" version of the custom_edit_text instead of the -v29.

What needs to be done so that the appropriate drawable ends up in the layout based upon the api version of the phone in question?

[project resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlO2L.png)

[activity main v29](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s72o.png)

Comment: What version of Android is the Galaxy S9 running?

Comment: The Galaxy S9 is running api 28, which confuses me. i don't understand how this phone has a dark mode feature if it's an api level lower then what the feature was released in. I originally thought the phone was on the latest api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite likely that the S9 does not support api level 29 as that equals to Android 10 which is quite new.

You would need to have a `drawable-v26` to ensure the Galaxy S9 woulds work as they shipped with Android 8 I believe.

Comment: The phone in question is at api 29. The option for dark mode is in her drop down menu. The rest of the layout is appropriate for dark mode, just not the drawable.

Comment: Correction, the phone is on api 28. How then does this phone have a dark mode? I thought the Google was releasing dark mode in android Q api 29.

Comment: This is what fixed it, once the drawables were in an appropriate folder they showed up as expected. Thank you.